# How to convert a 2D Numpy object array containing same-length lists to a normal 3D Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types, casting

I have a 2D object array of arrays of the same size, and I want to convert this to an ordinary 3D array. The array dimensions are huge, so this should preferably be done in an optimized and in-place way.

I found a question about doing this for an 1D array containing arrays of size 1, but the solutions, and anything else I tried, are failing with the same error:

`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

The code below generates an array similar to mine, and presents two solutions I tried:

```py
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])              # in my real case, this has about 5000 items
arr = np.empty((3,3), dtype=object)  # in my real case, this is a 400x400 array
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        arr[i,j] = x 

# Simplest way fails:
x_new = arr.astype(int)

# solution for the length=1 question fails:
x_new = np.stack(arr).astype(None)
```

How to do this successfully? Why do I even get this error?

##### *Answer:*

I figured it out at the end, and posted the solution as an answer to ["How to convert an object array to a normal array in python?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30666403/5099168), since it works for arbitrary dimensions including 1D:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72714279/5099168*

Comment: Does this solve the issue? `arr = np.empty((3, 3, 1, 4), dtype=np.int64)` for using by loops, or just use `arr = np.full((3, 3, 1, 4), x, dtype=np.int64)`

Comment: @Ali_Sh the way I generate `arr` is to provide an array with a similar structure to mine. My array is loaded from a Numpy save, created by someone else as the result of days-long simulations. Consider it as given.

Comment: If you want to put arrays in just some indices of the `arr` and leave others (as where values, not arrays), you should convert the `arr` to list of lists and then make changes.

Comment: Nope, I want to treat the whole array as a 3D Numpy array, so I can perform parallelized Numpy/Scipy manipulations like FFT, amax, etc. along specific axes. I tried `np.array(list(arr))` but it just gave me back the same array.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if I use `print(arr)` then I see `[array([1, 2, 3, 4]) array([1, 2, 3, 4]), ...]`. And this makes problem to set `astype(int)`. If I define `arr` with size `(3,3,4)`  instead of `(3,3)` then I get 3D array `[[[1 2 3 4] [1 2 3 4] [1 2 3 4]] ...` and `.astype(int)` works

Comment: I've a little confused what the OP need for final expected array. I think if he put an expected final array, it can show what he exactly want from the proposed code. `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` I guess, this error is because the OP is assigning an array to each indices (which contained a value before and, now, the main array assumes this assigned array as an element not an array ==> `arr.shape` will remain as `(3, 3)`)  so the code can not convert that inner array to int (each values in that array must be converted to int).

Comment: @Ali_Sh, he's using the `np.empty` construct to create a example 2d array object dtype array.  It's the only way to make a object dtype array containing arrays that match in shape.  `np.array(alist, object)` only works when the arrays in the list differ in shape (on the first dimension).

Comment: @Ali_Sh that's exactly the issue, but it's not my mistake. Our group has a code that calculates an 1D array for all points of a certain 2D parameter space, places them into a 2D object array, and saves this array using `numpy.save`. There are reasons why (involving parallelization, legacy codes, etc.), but ultimately it's none of my business. What I have to do is use the arrays I `numpy.load`. What I want is, in my example, to basically convert `arr` from having `arr.shape == (3,3); arr.dytpe==object` to `x_new.shape == (3,3,4); x_new.dtype == int`.

Comment: The deeper issue is simply that numpy doesn't recognize that my object array consists of arrays of the same length, and could be converted to a regular array; so it doesn't even tries to do that and fails.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a 2d object dtype array:

```
In [110]: arr
Out[110]: 
array([[array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([1, 2, 3, 4])],
       [array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([1, 2, 3, 4])],
       [array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([1, 2, 3, 4])]],
      dtype=object)

In [111]: arr.shape
Out[111]: (3, 3)
```

One option it convert it to a list (of lists), and make array from that.  Note, you had to use the `np.empty` construct to get around the normal `np.array` action that does just this:

```
In [117]: arr.tolist()
Out[117]: 
[[array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([1, 2, 3, 4])],
 [array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([1, 2, 3, 4])],
 [array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([1, 2, 3, 4])]]

In [118]: np.array(arr.tolist())
Out[118]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4]],

       [[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4]],

       [[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4]]])
```

`np.stack` can convert a 1d array:

```
In [119]: np.stack(arr.ravel())
Out[119]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

which can then be reshaped.

`np.stack(arr)` because it actually does `np.stack(list(arr))`.  `list(arr)` is a list of object dtype arrays - with the same shape.  `np.array(arr[i],int)` has the same `sequence` error.  That's why stack only works to convert 1d arrays (or lists), not 2d.